# What are you? Your fifth is in cookies but never in cream. -- a riddle

Tags: riddle, word

Your fifth is in cookies but never in cream. 
Your fourth is in stormclouds and also in steam.

Your last's in your meaning but not in your word.
Your second's in fourth, first, three-hundredth, and third.

Your first's in a puddle but not in a pail.
Your third and your sixth, when abroad, are in jail.

You minify mountains, cause floodgates to fail.
What are you?

---

Hint, in case of emergency:

> If you're really stuck, consider the 26th and 28th words of the riddle.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> **EROSION**

---

Your first's in a puddle but not in a pail.

> '**E**' is in 'puddl**e**' and not in the word 'pail'

Your second's in fourth, first, three-hundredth, and third.

> **R** is in all four words: fou**r**th, fi**r**st, th**r**ee-hund**r**eth and thi**r**d.

Your third and your sixth, when abroad, are in jail.

> **O** is in 'ga**o**l' - a old British term for jail

Your fourth is in stormclouds and also in steam.

> **S** is of course in '**s**tormclouds' and in '**s**team'

Your fifth is in cookies but never in cream.

> **I** is in 'cook**i**es' and not in the word 'cream'

Your third and your sixth, when abroad, are in jail.

> **O** - Same as the first one

Your last's in your meaning but not in your word.

> **N** is in 'mea**n**i**n**g' but not in the word 'word'

---

You minify mountains, cause floodgates to fail.

> **EROSION** causes mountains to erode over time, and with enough erosion a floodgate would fail

What are you?

> **Erosion**!

---

Hint:

> The 26th and 28th words are ‘in word’. And indeed, the answer was found by taking the letters from in the words!

Comment: Beautifully done! rot13(jung v unq va zvaq sbe guveq naq fvkgu jnf "tnby".)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil 26th and 28th *words*, not *letters*.

Comment: @Hellion ahhhh there we go, thank you :P

Comment: Is “when abroad” just meant to mean “British”?  And if so, can I register a mild complaint about the US-centric phrasing there?  As a Brit, it completely threw me off.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Very fair point. I wasn't happy with the phrasing either, and could only hope that rot13(gur Nzrevpna fcryyvat bs wnvy) would betray the author's location.